# Push/Fetch command for Git in QtCreator works only in Remotes-menu

Tags: git, github, push, qt-creator, git-fetch

I'm currently fighting with QtCreator 2.5.0 and Git. I initialized a local repo in my project's root-directory. After that I added my remote repo on GitHub (SSH key etc. - all set). For some reason though QtCreator refuses to push/fetch my code to the remote repo when I use Tools->Git->Push/Fetch. However if I go to Tool->Git->Remotes... and pus/fetch from there it is working. Needless to say this is at least for me a very strange behaviour. The pushing from inside my terminal is also not an issue and works like a charm.

Here is what I've done so far:

- I've checked with git in terminal to see if everything is set as you can see below.

  ```
  USER:~/QtProjects/TestProject$ git remote -v
  TestProject git@github.com:USERNAME/TestProject.git (fetch)
  TestProject git@github.com:USERNAME/TestProject.git (push)
  ```
- Pushed/Fetched a couple of times in terminal with success (result was also visible on GitHub/local repo)
- Pushed/Fetched a couple of times in Remotes-menu of QtCreator with success (result was also visible on GitHub/local repo):

  ```
  21:46 Executing in /home/USER/QtProjects/TestProject: /usr/bin/git push TestProject
  Everything up-to-date
  The command '/usr/bin/git' finished successfully.
  ```
- Pushed/Fetched a couple of times using Tools->Git->Push/Fetch with failure.

Now I've noticed that when pushing using Tools->Git->Push/Fetch I get an empty string where my repo's name should be standing as displayed above along with the good old error of a missing push destination (below I've marked it with MISSING_REPO_NAME_HERE):

```
21:46 Executing in /home/redbaron/QtProjects/HskaCompiler: /usr/bin/git push MISSING_REPO_NAME_HERE
fatal: No configured push destination.
Either specify the URL from the command-line or configure a remote repository using

git remote add <name> <url>

and then push using the remote name

git push <name>

The command '/usr/bin/git' terminated with exit code 128.
```

Has anyone experienced something like this and maybe know how to fix it? I recently switched from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32bit with don't know which version of QtCreator (I guess the latest in the repos of Precise) to Debian Wheezy 7.6 64bit. In Ubuntu I didn't encounter such an issue. The most interesting thing here is that what QtCreator actually does is call **git remote -v** the same way I do - in the project's root directory. In one case (Remotes-menu) it works, in the other - not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is some kind of a bug either in Qt Creator or git (at least the version that I'm using), or both.